# Font sizes in UIWebView does NOT match iOS font size

Tags: ios, css, uiwebview, retina-display

Here's a UILabel which says "About". Set at exactly 17.7 in iOS.

Below it a UIWebView which also says "About".  Also set at exactly 17.7 using css.

[image]

They don't match.

How to fix this correctly?

It is **bizarre that in Apple's own UIWebView, the size basis is different**?

Html to test...

```
<html><head>
<style type='text/css'>
body {
margin: 0px;
font-family: 'SourceSansPro-Light';
font-size: FONTPOINTSpt;
}
html { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }
</style></head>
<body leftmargin=0 topmargin=0>
About
</body></html>
```

Behavior is identical on device or simulator.

(Note, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11786118/294884) I learned the ratio is, perhaps 72.0/96.0.)

Comment: Check the font-size of the parent containers to the two About controls.  I bet one of them already has a font-size set on it.  If thats the case when you set the font-size for the About it takes the parents font-size into consideration.  If I can see your HTML and CSS it might be more clear.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want a 1 to 1 relationship between the font size that the `UILabel` uses and the font size that the `UIWebView` uses (via CSS) you have to use `px` instead of `pt` when defining the font size in your CSS.

Checkout this example HTML / CSS:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type='text/css'>
            body {
               font-family: 'SourceSansPro-Regular';
               padding: 0
            }
            .point {
                font-size: 17pt
            }
            .pixel {
                font-size: 17px
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="point">About (17pt)<p>
        <p class="pixel">About (17px)</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

When you add a `UIWebView` and a `UILabel` to your `UIViewController` and load the above HTML to the `UIWebView` and set the same font to the `UILabel`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 25, y: 50, width:325 , height: 90))
    view.addSubview(webView)

    let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("test", withExtension: "html")
    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: filePath!))

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 25, y: 150, width: 325, height: 40))
    label.font = UIFont(name: "SourceSansPro-Regular", size: 17)
    label.text = "About (UILabel set to 17)"
    view.addSubview(label)
}
```

You get the following output:

[image]

Comment: This did not work with `WKWebView`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45998220/the-font-looks-like-smaller-in-wkwebview-than-in-uiwebview) for fix.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion was because CSS pt is a typographic point (1/72 in), but Apple's iOS documentation uses "point" (e.g. UIFont.pointSize) as "virtual pixel", which corresponds to CSS px.  Judging from @joern's answer, it looks like UIWebView uses 1 css px = 1 ios virtual px. (I have not tested this.)  However, in my tests with WKWebView, it looks like CSS px is equal to one device pixel.  So for WKWebView, you want:

```
let fontSize = UIScreen.main.scale * label.font.pointSize
let cssStr = String(format:"font-size: %.1fpx;", fontSize)
```

Answer (score -3):

Yep, its a parent font-size issue:

You should always set the font-size for body to 16px (one can set it higher if a larger base font is required, the standard is 16px).

Then, set font sizes using 16px as the base.

```
body {
    font-size: 16px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

If you want both the body and the h1 font-sizes to be the same then simply set the body font-size and don't set the font-size of the h1 (it will inherit the body font-size all on its own... aka... cascading).

```
body {
    font-size: 16px;
}

h1 {

}
```

What you have done is set the body font-size to a value... then set the h1 font-size to that same value, the problem is that h1 inherits the font-size from body and then goes even bigger when you assign a font-size to h1.

Hope this makes sense and helps.

Comment: yes, give it a try and let me know if that was the solution ;)

Comment: Are you using a normalize.css some where?  Sounds like the H1 has a default setting of 40px set in a normalize or the like.  Maybe you can set the h1 font-size at the source