# The font looks like smaller in WKWebView than in UIWebView

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

I changed `UIWebView` to `WKWebView`, however, with the same html, the font in `WKWebView` looks like smaller than in `UIWebView`. I don't want this happen, so is there any way to avoid this change?

Comment: try injecting this line in your html <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1.0\" />

Comment: I am facing same issue after adopting WKWebView with Xcode 11.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem by adding an html string:

- **For Objective-C:**

```
NSString *headString = @"<head><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'></head>";
[self.webView loadHTMLString:[headString stringByAppendingString:yourHTMLString] baseURL:nil];
```

- **For Swift:**

```
let headString = "<head><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'></head>"
webView.loadHTMLString(headString + yourHTMLString, baseURL: nil)
```

---

What's more,if you want to load url rather than html you can try:

```swift
private var isInjected: Bool = false
webView.navigationDelegate = self
// MARK: - WKNavigationDelegate
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    if isInjected == true {
        return
    }
    self.isInjected = true
    // get HTML text
    let js = "document.body.outerHTML"
    webView.evaluateJavaScript(js) { (html, error) in
        let headString = "<head><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'></head>"
        webView.loadHTMLString(headString + (html as! String), baseURL: nil)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks this was helpful! This was default behavior for UIWebView. Just note, if you like to let user control the zoom in/out like a web browser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26720053/2697217

Comment: Facing same issue, i have already added above HTML. migrated from xcode 10.3 to xcode 11

Comment: This does work but the HTML content first appears small and then becomes normal. It's fast but still visible.

Comment: Thanks - workd for me in VS2019 for Windows With Xamarin.
Just included the <Head> tag 'as is' into my Html

Answer (score 27):

```
let description = "<p> HTML content <p>"
var headerString = "<header><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0'></header>"
headerString.append(description)              
self.webView.loadHTMLString("\(headerString)", baseURL: nil)
```

Comment: Hi, How to do this when I am loading webview with URL. Font is size smaller in WkWebview compared with UiWebview using same URL.

Comment: @Saravanan in above given example self.webView is a WKWebview object.

Answer (score 24):

Simple way to do this in **Swift**

```
extension WKWebView {

    /// load HTML String same font like the UIWebview
    ///
    //// - Parameters:
    ///   - content: HTML content which we need to load in the webview.
    ///   - baseURL: Content base url. It is optional.
    func loadHTMLStringWithMagic(content:String,baseURL:URL?){
        let headerString = "<header><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'></header>"
        loadHTMLString(headerString + content, baseURL: baseURL)
    }
}
```

Just simply call this method and magic happen. ;)

```
webView.loadHTMLStringWithMagic(content: "<p> HTML content <p>", baseURL: nil)
```

**OUTPUT:**
[image]

Comment: Saved the day, Thanks.

Comment: nit: 'head' not 'header'

Answer (score 3):

From iOS 14 onward you can achieve this with pageZoom property. For example

```
webView.pageZoom = 2.0;
```

will make page content twice as large.

Here's the link for documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/3516411-pagezoom

Comment: This is the only working solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

This code work for me:

```
func fill(_ model:NewsModel){
    let description = "<p>\(model.details) <p>"
    var headerString = "<header><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0'></header>"
    headerString.append(description)
    self.detailsTestWebView.loadHTMLString("\(headerString)", baseURL: nil)
}
```

Comment: though is it good that you are providing answers, but it would be better if you explain in brief your code -FROM REVIEW

Answer (score 0):

We can insert Headers into html throght javaScrip insertAdjacentHTML function in WKNavigationDelegate didFinish navigation method

```
extension HelpScreenViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
// MARK: - WKNavigationDelegate
public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    guard !isInjected else  {
        return
    }
    self.isInjected = true
    let js = """
             document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin',"<header><meta 
             name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, 
             maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'> 
             </header>")
             """
    webView.evaluateJavaScript(js) { (html, error) in
    }
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by injecting the JavaScript code provided above in a neat way. Here is the way I instantiate `WKWebView`.

```swift
private func makeWebView() -> WKWebView {
    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let ctr = WKUserContentController()
    config.userContentController = ctr
    // JavaScript to inject
    let src = """
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin',"<header><meta
    name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,
    maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'>
    </header>");
    """
    let script = WKUserScript(source: src,
                              injectionTime: .atDocumentStart,
                              forMainFrameOnly: false)
    ctr.addUserScript(script)
    
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.uiDelegate = self

    return webView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to scale the content by applying a zoom to JavaScript directly:

```swift
func scaleWebViewTextContent(_ webView: WKWebView, _ multiplier: Double) {
    let jsCode =
    """
    var scale = \(multiplier);
    document.body.style.zoom = scale;
    """
    webView.evaluateJavaScript(jsCode)
}
```

Comment: btw, if would face any problem with headers(h1, h2, h3 etc) can use `document.documentElement.style.fontSize="\(multiplier*100)%"` instead