# SwiftUI a Tag View in the middle of a Text

Tags: swiftui

I have Name `Max` and text. I would like the text to be right after line truncation on the left side (without having whitespace). Is such a thing possible in SwiftUI?

Photo:

[image]

The code I am currently using is this:

```swift
struct NotificationUser: View {
    var name: String
    var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            Text(name)
            .bold()
            .padding(.horizontal, 5)
            .padding(.vertical, 2)
            .background(Color(.systemGray6))
            .cornerRadius(5)
            
            Text(text)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want "has just ..." to be below Max and at the Left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Attributed String

You can get help from attributed string that [I explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59531265/5623035) and it has full access for what you are looking for.

---

## More native SwiftUI

Also, you can just use this hack:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
        Text(name)
            .bold()
            .padding(.horizontal, 5)
            .padding(.vertical, 2)
            .background(Color(.systemGray6))
            .cornerRadius(5)

        Group {
            Text(name) // This goes as a frame holder
                .bold()
                .foregroundColor(.clear)

                + Text("  " + text)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 5)
        .padding(.vertical, 2)
    }
}
```

## Result

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

This is a Tags view I wrote for iOS 13 and above.
It's a multiline text field with tags deletable.

https://github.com/lijin88121/TagTextField

[image]