# SwiftUI: Use of different colours within same Text view

Tags: colors, swiftui

I have a section of text where I am using .replacingOccurrences to display the users' answer within the question sentence:

```
           Text((question.text)
                .replacingOccurrences(of: "_____", with:
                    question.answers[question.userAnswer]
                ))
                .font(Font.custom("ClearSans-Bold", size: 18))
                .foregroundColor(.black )
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
```

I want the users' answer `question.answers[question.userAnswer]` to be a different colour (red/green) to the main body of the text (similar to attached image) however I'm new to SwiftUI so not sure how to add this in.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUvtQ.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Attributed String in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59531122/how-to-use-attributed-string-in-swiftui)

Comment: You can join `Text` with different modifiers. For example you could have `Text("Hello").foregroundColor(.red) + Text("World").foregroundColor(.blue)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extension for `String` that does pretty much what you want:

```
extension String {
    func replacingOccurrences(of: String, with: [Text]) -> Text {
        return self.components(separatedBy: of).enumerated().map({(i, s) in
            return i < with.count ? Text(s) + with[i] : Text(s)
        }).reduce(Text(""), { (r, t) in
            return r + t
        })
    }
}
```

It uses concatenation of Text elements as George_E suggested. You can use it like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let question: String = "The witch found the concoction extremely _____. _____ makes better ones."

    let answers: [String] = ["nauseate", "A friend of her's"]

    var body: some View {
        question.replacingOccurrences(of: "_____", with: self.answers.map({s in Text(s).foregroundColor(.red)})).foregroundColor(.secondary)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

You may want to add some extra code for handling cases where the number of answers does not match the occurrences of `_____`.