# SwiftUI: How-to append view to ending of multiline text?

Tags: swiftui

## Current

I have something like the following:

Short text with badge:

[image]

It's done simple with HStack atm:

```
HStack {
    Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.")
        .font(.title2)
    Text("foo")
        .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .bold))
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .padding(.horizontal, 4)
        .padding(.vertical, 2)
        .background(Color.red)
        .cornerRadius(5)
}
```

My Problem is that the main text is multiline and if it wraps, it looks like this:

Larger multiline text with badge:

[image]

## Goal

But my goal is that the foo badge is always displayed after the last word of the main text, which should look like this:

Goal: Solution like Text + Text:

[image]

In other words I want the same behaviour as if I would use the concatenating feature of SwiftUI's Text (`Text() + Text()`), but I can't use that because of the formatting of the badge. The formatting modifiers like `background()` will change the return type to `View` and then the `+` operator doesn't work anymore.

What is the most elegant solution to achieve my goal? I would prefer not using UIKit.

Comment: Probably this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59531122/how-to-use-attributed-string-in-swiftui can be helpful. Second answer.

Comment: @ezaji You mean the third answer, the custom AttributedText implementation? Second answer, the + operator I can't use because of the background and padding stuff changing the return type, like I've described.

Comment: Yes, third answer is more appropriate for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using "+" operator :

```
Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.")
+
Text("foo")
    .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .bold))
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .padding(.horizontal, 4)
    .padding(.vertical, 2)
    .background(Color.red)
    .cornerRadius(5)
```

This will give you the desired result, and automatically align the view at the end of the first view, without hardcoding anything.

Answer (score 0):

This below solution gives the result but, the badge will be at the end of the line.
If, it is static text, you can use `offset(x: )` to achieve that manually.

```
ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
       Text("But my goal is that the foo badge is always displayed after the last word of the main text, which should look like this:")
           .font(.title2)

       Text("foo")
           .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .bold))
           .foregroundColor(.white)
           .padding(.horizontal, 4)
           .padding(.vertical, 2)
           .background(Color.red)
           .cornerRadius(5)
           .alignmentGuide(.bottom) { d in d[.bottom] }
           // .offset(x: 50)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the text is dynamic, could be everything from 1 to 160 characters