# NSAttributedString in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uitextview, nsattributedstring

everyone. I am trying to show `NSAttributedString` in `SwiftUI`. Since `SwiftUI` doesn't have any controls capable of it,
I am trying to use `UIKit` controls, wrapped in `UIViewRepresentable`. I've tried to use `UILabel`, but it doesn't handle hyperlinks.
I've tried to use `UITextView` (`isScrollEnabled = false`) but in this case text isn't broken into lines (see screenshot). When `isScrollEnabled` is set to `true`,
`UITextView` is displayed correctly, but I don't want any scroll.

I would be very glad to hear any suggestions.[image]

**Update:** I get text from the server and I need to apply different format to different (but often intersecting!) parts of text. For example: Characters [0, 10] should be bold, characters [5, 10] should be a link, etc. I'd hate to do the parsing manually and check that no part of text is repeated. `NSAttributedString` has a method `string.addAttribute(.font, value: font, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 10))`

**Update 2:** We support iOS 14+

Comment: "Since SwiftUI doesn't have any controls capable of it" How about `Text`?

Comment: For iOS 13 and 14, you can check out [my repo](https://github.com/Orijhins/SwiftUIPlus). It was made with macOS in mind, but your implementation of my PlusTextView (tags aside) should be close

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59531122/how-to-use-attributed-string-in-swiftui

Comment: **Found my problem solved [here](https://gonzalezreal.github.io/2020/01/31/rendering-attributed-strings-in-swiftui.html)**