# Display text with bulleted list from firebase in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am pulling down text from firebase and in one of the strings is a bulleted list e.g:

"""

The second part of the thesis will consist of;

- Building life span and flexibility   requirements
- Project expectations

The design brief will research and analyse how existing buildings are built for cold climates and digital nomadic living by looking at numerous categories;

"""

Im trying to figure out what the best way to deal with this is.

Is it possible to use `Attributed` text and a swiftUI `Text` view.

Is the only way to do this using a WKWebView and update the string to be in HTML with all the HTML markdown added etc.

Comment: This question is slightly unclear - is your question how you can make a bulleted list in SwiftUI from a list in firebase?

Comment: Its a question of whats the best route, from what i can see it looks like WKWebview and then make the text in firebase formatted in HTML

Comment: Yes, I would agree with that. SwiftUI can display text in markdown if you wanted to try to format your text so it can be displayed in that way too.

Comment: From what i can see it doesnt recognise the markdown for bullet points, but maybe i set it up worng

Comment: Then you could try, instead of a `Text`, an `AttributedString` as you suggested above. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59531122/how-to-use-attributed-string-in-swiftui

Comment: This might help too. https://swiftui-lab.com/attributed-strings-with-swiftui/ https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributedstring/

Comment: AttributedString markdown doesnt seem to recognise bullet points which is annoying

Comment: In that case, I would go with your original WebView idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244514/discussion-between-mr-developer-and-wazza).