# How to display the HTML text in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

My requirement is to display the text in `SwiftUI` which contains the `HTML` tags. I tried with the approach of using the `WKWebKit::Loadhtml` which works fine . However, I have the requirement of displaying it something like this.
A collection of person card

Person card:-
Name     Title

Person details details which has HTML text e.gHello world

Can someone suggest a way to solve this in `SwiftUI`.

Refer to the post as well but no luck

[How to show HTML or Markdown in a SwiftUI Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56892691/how-to-show-html-or-markdown-in-a-swiftui-text/56895086#56895086)

Comment: Literally the post you link to shows you how to use UIViewRepresentable to wrap a WKWebView in a SwiftUI.View.  What did you try and what error are you getting?

Comment: I was looking for an example how to use UIViewRepresentable with an UILabel and attributedText.However, I think deriving a class using the WKWebView solves the issue. Incase if you have pointers how can i implement the UIViewRepresentable then let me know.

Comment: I am working on a blog which could help lot of people like me

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/67500889/10952522.

Answer (score 4):

There are a range of ways to display HTML text in SwiftUI. However I found some issues to use them. Interfacing `UILabel` and using `NSAttributedText` only enable us to display small size string moreover `WKWebView` restrict to use desirable font. Considering all of these, I found using `UITextView` with `NSAttributedText` is more convenient to display HTML text in SwiftUI. The code is following

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

struct HTMLFormattedText: UIViewRepresentable {

   let text: String
   private  let textView = UITextView()

   init(_ content: String) {
      self.text = content
   }

   func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) -> UITextView {
      textView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:UIScreen.main.bounds.width).isActive = true
      textView.isSelectable = false
      textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
      textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      textView.isScrollEnabled = false
      return textView
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) {
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
         if let attributeText = self.converHTML(text: text) {
             textView.attributedText = attributeText
         } else {
             textView.text = ""
         }

     }
  }

  private func converHTML(text: String) -> NSAttributedString?{
      guard let data = text.data(using: .utf8) else {
          return nil
      }

      if let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) {
          return attributedString
      } else{
          return nil
      }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {    
    var body: some View {
       HTMLFormattedText("<p>Danish-made 1st class kebab</p><p><br></p><p>Say yes thanks to 2kg. delicious kebab, which is confused and cooked.</p><p><br></p><p>Yes thanks for 149.95</p><p><br></p><p>Now you can make the most delicious sandwiches, kebab mix and much more at home</p>")        
    }
}
```

Here height will increase automatically based on the size of content as well as width also.
More detail is available on this GitHub link: https://github.com/tmusabe/HTMLFormattedText-SwiftUI

Comment: Thank you. This is the only code in all stackoverflow that works for me!