# Delegate for external link clicked in SwiftUI HtmlView

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm using a HTMLView from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68498657/11734662)

But sometimes I have a link, if I click that opens Safari

Does exist in SwiftUI some *delegate* to catch the link with this HTMLView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `UITextDelegate` of the `UITextView` to the `Coordinator` of the `UIViewRepresentable`. Then, you can decide how to process URLs in `shouldInteractWith`. If you return `false`, the system will not use Safari to navigate to the URL.

```
struct HTMLFormattedText: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let text: String
    
    init(_ content: String) {
        self.text = content
    }
    
    class Coordinator : NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
            print(URL)
            return false
        }
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let attributeText = self.converHTML(text: text) {
                uiView.attributedText = attributeText
            } else {
                uiView.text = ""
            }
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator()
    }
    
    private func converHTML(text: String) -> NSAttributedString?{
        guard let data = text.data(using: .utf8) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        if let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) {
            return attributedString
        } else{
            return nil
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HTMLFormattedText("Test<br/><a href=\"https://google.com\">Google</a>")
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you 