# How to render HTML String in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm in need of rendering a html string in my swiftui app.

I found this:  [How to show HTML or Markdown in a SwiftUI Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56892691/how-to-show-html-or-markdown-in-a-swiftui-text)

But I tried every single solution there and I get a blank screen!

This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit


struct HTMLStringView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let htmlContent: String

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.loadHTMLString(htmlContent, baseURL: nil)
    }
}


struct audioInfoView: View {
    
    let longDetails: String

    
    var body : some View{
        
        ScrollView{
            
            ZStack{
                
                HTMLStringView(htmlContent: "<p>\(longDetails)</p>")
                
                //Text(longDetails)
             
                
            }.padding()
        }.padding(.top,50)
        
    }
}
```

The `let longDetails: String` is a string with html tags that's being passed on from another view.

If I do `Text(longDetails)`, I can see the text and all the html tags but when I do  `HTMLStringView(htmlContent: "<p>\(longDetails)</p>")`, I see nothing and it only displays a blank screen!

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WKWebView` has a scroll view in it and you *also* have the `HTMLStringView` wrapped in a `ScrollView`, leading to some layout conflicts.

Options:

1. Remove the outer `ScrollView`:

```
var body : some View{
        HTMLStringView(htmlContent: "<p>\(longDetails)</p>")
    }
```

2. Pass an explicit height:

```
var body : some View{
    ScrollView{
        ZStack{
            HTMLStringView(htmlContent: "<p>\(longDetails)</p>")
                .frame(height: 200)
        }.padding()
    }.padding(.top,50)
}
```

What you choose may vary based on your use case. You may also want to explore `.isScrollEnabled` on `WKWebView` if you don't want the `WKWebView` to be scrollable. And, it seems like you may also end up with a case where you need to find the height of the `WKWebView` content: [How to determine the content size of a WKWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27515236/how-to-determine-the-content-size-of-a-wkwebview)