# SwiftUI Text Markdown dynamic string not working

Tags: text, swiftui

I want to dynamically deliver content and display hyperlinks, but it can’t be delivered dynamically and doesn’t work

```
let linkTitle = "Apple Link"
let linkURL = "http://www.apple.com"
let string = "[Apple Link](http://www.apple.com)"
            
Text(string)        // Not working

Text("[Apple Link](http://www.apple.com)")  // Working
            
Text("[\(linkTitle)](http://www.apple.com)")    // Working
            
Text("[\(linkTitle)](\(linkURL))")  // Not working
```

Comment: hmm, does not work for me as well. You may have to resort to: "Link(linkTitle, destination: URL(string: linkURL)!)"

Comment: @workingdog I am implementing hashtags(#) and mentions(@) Text very perfect, I only need to customize the URL Schemes, but unfortunately I can’t pass the string dynamically

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can try this taken from: [How to show HTML or Markdown in a SwiftUI Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56892691/how-to-show-html-or-markdown-in-a-swiftui-text) halfway down the page.

```
extension String {
    func markdownToAttributed() -> AttributedString {
        do {
            return try AttributedString(markdown: self) /// convert to AttributedString
        } catch {
            return AttributedString("Error parsing markdown: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    let linkTitle = "Apple Link"
    let linkURL = "https://www.apple.com"
    let string = "[Apple Link](https://www.apple.com)"
       
    @State var textWithMarkdown = "[Apple Link](https://www.apple.com)"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Text(textWithMarkdown.markdownToAttributed()) // <-- this works
            
            Text(string)        // Not working

            Text("[Apple Link](http://www.apple.com)")  // Working
                        
            Text("[\(linkTitle)](http://www.apple.com)")    // Working
                        
            Text("[\(linkTitle)](\(linkURL))")  // Not working
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Simple and effective, can be processed into AttributedString. Thank you

Answer (score 24):

## Short Answer

Wrap the string in `AttributedString(markdown: my_string_here)`:

```
let string: String = "[Apple Link](http://www.apple.com)"
Text(try! AttributedString(markdown: string))
```

## Extension

```
extension String {
  func toMarkdown() -> AttributedString {
    do {
      return try AttributedString(markdown: self)
    } catch {
      print("Error parsing Markdown for string \(self): \(error)")
      return AttributedString(self)
    }
  }
}
```

## Long Answer

SwiftUI `Text` has multiple initializers.

For [`String`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:)-9d1g4):

```
init<S>(_ content: S) where S : StringProtocol
```

For [`AttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:)-1a4oh):

```
init(_ attributedContent: AttributedString)
```

When you declare a static string, Swift is able to guess whether the intent is to use a `String` or `AttributedString` (Markdown). However, when you use a dynamic string, Swift needs help in figuring out your intent.

As a result, with a dynamic string, you have to explicitly convert your `String` into an `AttributedString`:

```
try! AttributedString(markdown: string)
```

Answer (score 16):

Add another `.init` in text.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let linkTitle = "Apple Link"
    let linkURL = "http://www.apple.com"
    let string = "[Apple Link](http://www.apple.com)"
    
    var body: some View {
    
        Text(.init(string))     // <== Here!
        
        Text("[Apple Link](http://www.apple.com)")  // Working
        
        Text("[\(linkTitle)](http://www.apple.com)")    // Working
        
        Text(.init("[\(linkTitle)](\(linkURL))"))  // <== Here!
    }
}
```

Comment: This works because calling the init creates a `LocalisedString` that recognises markdown

Answer (score 1):

To define markdown string separately and then pass it to text, we should explicitly convert it to a localized string key. Because otherwise, SwiftUI will just treat this as a regular string and will not parse it internally.

```
let markdownStr = "Hello, **world**! Check out our [website](https: //example.com)!"
Text (LocalizedStringKey (markdownStr))
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Apple's Documentation On This](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributedstring)

#### Creating Attributed Strings with Markdown

You can create an attributed string by passing a standard String or Data instance that contains Markdown to initializers like init(markdown:options:baseURL:). The attributed string creates attributes by parsing the markup in the string.

```
do {
    let thankYouString = try AttributedString(
        markdown:"**Thank you!** Please visit our [website](https://example.com)")
} catch {
    print("Couldn't parse: \(error)")
}
```

Localized strings that you load from strings files with initializers like init(localized:options:table:bundle:locale:comment:) can also contain Markdown to add styling. In addition, these localized attributed string initializers can apply the replacementIndex attribute, which allows you to determine the range of replacement strings, whose order may vary between languages.

### Further Explanation

#### Why not to use the `LocalizedStringKey` init

The behavior where `LocalizedStringKey` effectively works as markdown is undocumented, and so we probably should ***not*** use `LocalizedStringKey` inits as this is not a guaranteed pattern. Future updates might change this, and so it's better to use the more appropriate component `AttributedString`.

You can check [apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/localizedstringkey) on this to see for yourself, but `LocalizedStringKey` documentation does not mention markdown.

##### Basically, we probably shouldn't do this:

`Text(.init(dynamicString))`
`Text(LocalizedStringKey(markdownStr))`

#### Why using `AttributedString` is the right answer

As a few people mentioned, using `AttributedString(markdown: dynamicString)` for dynamic strings is the right answer.

Using Text with a static string (i.e. `Text("[Apple Link](http://www.apple.com)")`) will work fine, but dynamic strings need to be typed to properly parse as markdown. @kgaidis explains this well.

#### Important Detail To Add

`try! AttributedString(markdown: dynamicString)` will strip the string of `\n` characters. In order to preserve these characters, you can pass options in the init like so:

```
    try! AttributedString(
        markdown: dynamicString,
        options: AttributedString.MarkdownParsingOptions(interpretedSyntax: .inlineOnlyPreservingWhitespace)
        // \n will be stripped unless this option is added.
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improved version of [workingdog support Ukraine's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68427665). The String extension uses the option to preserve the '\n' in the markdown string.

```
extension String {
var toMarkdownString: AttributedString {
    do {
        return try AttributedString(markdown: self,
                                    options: AttributedString.MarkdownParsingOptions(interpretedSyntax: .inlineOnlyPreservingWhitespace))
    } catch {
        return AttributedString("Error parsing markdown: \(error)")
    }
  }
}
```