# iOS 15 beta 4: AttributedString with Markdown not rendering in Text in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, ios15

I assumed this was a iOS 15 beta 1 or 2 bug, but as of beta 4 I'm still seeing this behavior, so perhaps I'm doing something wrong:
Text is supposed to render AttributedStrings with Markdown. It appears to render correctly when a direct String literal is passed into the Text, but not when the AttributedString is a variable. Am I doing something super dumb?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var text = AttributedString("**Hello**, `world`! Visit our [website](https://www.capitalone.com).")

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("**Hello**, `world`! Visit our [website](https://www.capitalone.com).")
                .padding()

            Text(text)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: see my answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68426768/swiftui-text-markdown-dynamic-string-not-working/68427665#68427665

Comment: Try my `markdownToAttributed` extension: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67888726/14351818

Comment: Note: "my answer" is entirely the work of @aheze.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you pass Markdown directly into a `Text.init()`, SwiftUI will auto-convert it into an `AttributedString`.

However, to go from a Markdown string to an `AttributedString`, you need to use an [explicit `AttributedString(markdown:options:baseURL:)` initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributedstring/3796160-init). For example:

```swift
var text = try! AttributedString(markdown: "**Hello**, `world`! Visit our [website](https://www.capitalone.com).”)
```

Note that this initialiser throws if the conversion can’t be made correctly. I’ve used `try!` here because your example Markdown will definitely convert, but depending on the source of the Markdown text you may want to handle a thrown error a little more intelligently.

Comment: Ah! I knew I was doing something dumb! Thank you.