# SwiftUI Text Markdown support for string variables or string interpolation not working

Tags: ios, swift, string, swiftui

I'm trying to show my response data using SwiftUI `Text` with formatted text ex: **Bold**, but for some reason it's not working

The needed behaviour as below:

[image]

This is working!

```
Text("**Hello** *World*")
```

**But** this is not

```
let text: String = "**Hello** *World*"
Text(text)
```

Am I missing something

Comment: maybe duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/a/71090930/14733292

Comment: Different context, related answer 

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After test and fail moments, I found that Text only handles markdown when string literal is passed to initializer. as below:

to achieve the needed behavior:

```
let text: String = "**Hello** *World*"
    
Text("**Hello** *World*") // will be rendered with markdown formatting
Text(text) // will NOT be rendered according to markdown
Text(.init(text)) // will be rendered with markdown formatting
```

[image]

Comment: Early 2024, answer still helpful; thank you!